# how to echo my data only once if there's many data in my database

Tags: php, sql, database, for-loop, livesearch

this is my code

```
$sql = "select * from tbproduk where namaproduk LIKE '$produk%'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("error $sql");
$num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
for ($x = 1; $x <= $num; $x++) {
    $namaproduk = $result['namaproduk'];
    echo "<button style='color: black;text-align: left'><a style='padding: 0;line-height: 0;color: black;background: none' href='Konfirmasi/index4.php?produk=$namaproduk'>".$namaproduk ."</a></button><br>";
}
```

as you can see, it will echo all data in my database but i have the same data name in database. This is my database data.
[image: this is my database data]

so when it's echo it will be like this
[image: result]

how to loop my code once if there's the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select distinct records from data base. change your query as below:

```
$sql = "select DISTINCT namaproduk from tbproduk where namaproduk LIKE '$produk%'";
```

Comment: compare both answers you will get difference and also which is more appropriate @Rameshwar

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
$sql = "select * from tbproduk where namaproduk LIKE '$produk%' group by namaproduk";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it as:

```
$sql = "select distinct tp.namaproduk, tp.id, tp.harga, tp.pembeli, tp.namagmbr from tbproduk as tp where namaproduk LIKE '$produk%' ORDER BY id";
```

The MySql keyword `DISTINCT` does the trick.